# Is it possible to detect the default parameters of a function at compile-time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

```
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void f(int n = 7)
{}

void g(function<void()> fn)
{
    fn(); // same as f(7)
}

template<typename Callable>
auto GetDefaultArg(Callable fn, size_t arg_ordinal)
{
    // What to put here?
}

int main()
{
    auto fn = bind(f, GetDefaultArg(f, 1));
    g(fn);  
}
```

As illustrated in the code above, I want to implement a template function `GetDefaultArg` to detect the default paratemters of a function.

It it possible in current C++?

Comment: Do you need it to work for any callable thing? Or just for functions like `f`? What about `template<typename Param> auto GetDefaultArg(void (&) (Param), size_t arg_ordinal)`?

Comment: It's better if `GetDefaultArg` applys to any callable objects.

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? This sounds like the wrong approach.

Comment: I'd argue that, if you need to detect usage of the default value, that it would probably be better not to have a default value.   Force the caller to specify a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't detect the default parameter at compile time.

You have declared the default parameter within the function definition. But default parameters are not linked to the function itself, but the declaration of the function that is known in the scope where the function is called.

Otherwise stated: you could have different sets of default parameters for the same function.

Answer (score 3):

To add to [Chrisophe's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42920796/27678), I'll provide an example of what he means.

### We can redeclare a function later with additional defaults!

What does this mean?

Let's start with a function declaration:

```
// initial declaration; nothing defaulted
void foo(int a, char b, bool c, double d);
```

I have some function `foo` with no default arguments.
I write a function that calls `foo`:

```
void CallFoo1()
{
    // no default params
    foo(1, 'b', true, 2.0);
}
```

It must provide an argument for every parameter in `foo`.

However, now I can **redeclare** `foo` (so long as I haven't defined it yet), and give the last parameter a default value:

```
// add default for last argument
void foo(int a, char b, bool c, double d= 2.0);
```

Then I write *another* function that calls `foo`. Except this time I can leave the last argument empty:

```
void CallFoo2()
{
    foo(1, 'b', true);
}
```

I can continue to do this, redeclaring with a new defaulted value each time:

```
// add default for third argument
void foo(int a, char b, bool c=true, double d);

void CallFoo3()
{
    foo(1, 'b');
}

// add default for second argument
void foo(int a, char b='b', bool c, double d);

void CallFoo4()
{
    foo(1);
}

// add default for first argument
void foo(int a=1, char b, bool c, double d);

void CallFoo5()
{
    // everything is defaulted!
    foo();
}
```

After the last redeclaration of `foo`, the declaration of `foo` consists of the union of defaulted values (note: I can't re-default a value).

Then finally I can provide the definition for `foo`:

```
void foo(int a, char b, bool c, double d)
{
    std::cout << "a = " << a << " b = " << b << " c = " << std::boolalpha << c << " d = " << d << std::endl;
}
```

And let's try it out with a test:

```
int main()
{
    CallFoo1();
    CallFoo2();
    CallFoo3();
    CallFoo4();
    CallFoo5();
}
```

Output:

```
a = 1 b = b c = true d = 2
a = 1 b = b c = true d = 2
a = 1 b = b c = true d = 2
a = 1 b = b c = true d = 2
a = 1 b = b c = true d = 2
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/213f62312f9f02b2)